# Divisors of $2^n-1$ and primitivity in $F_{2^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Is there a classical (and efficient) algorithm to find all divisors of $2^n-1$ ?

This question comes to me when I tried to easily determine if some element $e$ of the finite field $F_2[X]/P(X)\equiv F_{2^n}$ (for some irreducible polynomial $P$ of degree $n$) is primitive. The only way I thought was to compute $e^d-1$ for all divisors $d$ of $2^n-1$, but I don't know if it can be done efficiently (quickly) for large $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known efficient algorithm for all n, but look at the cunningham project. You will be surprised how far the calculations have been made : 991 is the least n for which
$2^n-1$ is NOT completely factored!

There is a useful restriction to accelerate the search : Every prime factor of 
$2^p-1$ must be of the form $kp+1$ , if p is prime.

If p is not prime, you can first find algebraic factors by factoring the polynomial
$x^p-1$ and inserting 2 in the factors.

Comment: I did not know the $kp+1$ property. Where does it come from ?

Comment: The order o of n to base a is defined as the smallest nonzero number o, such that $a^o\equiv1\ (mod\ n)$. Let q be a prime factor of $2^p-1$. Because of $2^p\equiv1\ (mod\ q)$ the order of q to base 2 must divide p. If it would be 1, q would divide 2-1=1, which is impossible. So, the order must be p. Fermat's little theorem states $2^{q-1}\equiv1\ (mod\ q)$, hence p must divide q-1. Hence q must be of the form kp+1.